# How to find the closest result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Lets say I have an array with fields A, B, C, D, E, F whose value can be a `random number`

I use these fields to make a query `WHERE A = 'random number' AND B = 'random number' ... AND F = 'random number'`

If the result is empty then I remove last field from my array then run query `WHERE A = 'random number' AND B = 'random number' ... AND E = 'random number'`

This process repeats until I get the result.
Now, I found a new case where if I remove `D` field only and run the query, it returns the result.

I am not sure how to handle this case.

Comment: Show some code of your PHP query that you have tried.

Comment: What’s so special about this “new case” now? With your approach of removing the _last_ condition, you would at some point also be removing `D`, so that only the checks for A, B and C remain in place. How exactly is that not “enough” now to find your desired record? Proper explanation needed.

Comment: It will probably boil down to something like removing _all_ those conditions from the WHERE clause, select the differences between actual column content and the random value for each (maybe absolute), and then somehow order by that, and picking the top record …

Comment: Has the ‘random number’ in your example the same value for all fields?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to count how many columns in the row equal to that number, and take the row with the most matches. MySQL has a neat ability to treat boolean values as 0s and 1s in numeric contexts, so this can be done relatively easily (but note the operator precedence and the required parentheses):

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY (a = random_number) + 
         (b = random_number) + 
         (c = random_number) + 
         (d = random_number) + 
         (e = random_number) DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: @nas . . . This is a very reasonable operation, but it does not specifically address the question that you asked.  This counts the number of matches, returning a row with the most matches.  However, it does not remove the columns one-at-a-time.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, for now I am thinking of other solution. First let me finish my approach, then I will look for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to remove the *last* column at each step, then:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (a, b, c, d, e) = ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) desc,
         (a, b, c, d) = ($a, $b, $c, $d) desc,
         (a, b, c) = ($a, $b, $c) desc,
         (a, b) = ($a, $b) desc,
         a = $a desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  If there is no match then this will still return a row.  That seems to follow your pattern.

You can also use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (a = $a) desc,
         (b = $b) desc,
         (c = $c) desc,
         (d = $d) desc
         (e = $e) desc
limit 1;
```